# Как узнать длинну и кол-во объектов с определенным class'ом?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрые вечер:

имеем:

```
.superclass {
height: 170px;
padding-top: 30px;
}

<div class="superclass">Wow one</div>
<div class="superclass">Wow two</div>
<div class="superclass">Wow three</div>
<div class="superclass">Wow four</div>
```

Как узнать длинну(height) объекта и количество объектов c классом (superclass) на странице? (подключено jquery)

Comment: Суммарную ширину или ширину каждого элемента? А количество определяется просто:

    $('.superclass').length;

Comment: высоту каждого элемента. спасибо вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. называйте вещи своими именами: не длинна, а высота.
2. чтобы узнать высоту, нужно юзать метод $(".element").height();
3. Количество дочерных обьектов класса .class - $(".class").children().length;

Comment: спасибо вам, буду теперь знать что height это высота ;)